# ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#

Well I've started doing a project on C#, and it has object (class called `CLA`). CLA creates a set(list).

I will do function on `List<Cla>` and which needs `HighValue`, `LowValue` and so on. But `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` got in here.

Can i call method in constructor? Is this code correct?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Cla> ClaList = new List<Cla>();
        ClaList.Add(new Cla("a", 10.3, "Priznak1", 1));
        ClaList.Add(new Cla("b", 3.3, "Priznak1", 1));
        ClaList.Add(new Cla("c", 7.3, "Priznak1", 1));
        ClaList.Add(new Cla("d", 9.3, "Priznak1", 1));
        ClaList.Add(new Cla("e", 8.3, "Priznak1", 1));

        CritListSmall NewTest = new CritListSmall(ClaList);
        Console.WriteLine("ddd {0}", NewTest.HighValue);
    }
}


class CritListSmall
{
    public double HighValue;
    public double LowValue;

    public CritListSmall(List<Cla> p)
    {
        HighValue = p[0].ObjectValue;
        LowValue = p[0].ObjectValue;

        int NumberElements;

        NumberElements = p.Count;
        for (int i = 1; i <= NumberElements; i++)
        {
            double m = p[i].ObjectValue; //Exception occurs here
            if (HighValue < m)
                HighValue = m;
        }
        for (int l = 1; l <= NumberElements; l++)
        {
            double n = p[l].ObjectValue; //and here
            if (LowValue > n)
                LowValue = n;
        }
    }


    public class Cla
    {
        public string ObjectName;
        public double ObjectValue;
        public string PriznakName;
        public int ClassNumber;

        public Cla(string on, double ov, string pn, int cn)
        {
            ObjectName = on;
            ObjectValue = ov;
            PriznakName = pn;
            ClassNumber = cn;
        }

        public double CritValue;
        public double ExpValue;

        public bool Outlier;
        public double AbsoluteValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Lists are zero based.

Comment: Your for loop should never run until `<=count` because indexing starts with 0 ands ends with count -1. Change it to only `<count` and your loop will work just fine

Answer (score 2):

In C# collections have zero-based indexes. It means if you have 5 items in list, their indexes will be `0,1,2,3,4`. So instead of

```
for(int i = 1; i <= NumberElements; i++)
```

you should use

```
for(int i = 0; i < NumberElements; i++)
            ^    ^
     from zero   and less than count of items
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# array indexes start at `0`, not `1`, so you need to change your loops to be this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumberElements; i++)
```

And:

```
for (int l = 0; l < NumberElements; l++)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(int i = 1; i <= NumberElements; i++)
```

That is your problem. It must be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < NumberElements; i++)

for(int l = 0; l < NumberElements; l++)
```

Why? NumberElements is the count of p, for example 10. But the index is from 0 to 9.

Comment: Yes! thanks Sean it works

Comment: I'd just use `< n` instead of `<= n - 1`.

Comment: I think all answers are right, can you please mark one of them as accepted, with the hook under the vote down? I think it is helpful for other users with the same problem. Perhaps, you can make the SO tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour